# Executing alert(document.cookie) within an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is this possible ? i want to execute a alert(document.cookie) in a iframe , for ex:

```
<IFRAME SRC="http://example.com" onload="alert(document.cookie)"></IFRAME>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that of course, but it will display the cookies of the document containing the iframe, not of the one loaded inside.

Comment: i dont understand ... for example the cookie of src=http://example.com will be showed ?

Comment: No. This would be very bad since you could also process it, e.g. by sending it to a script that logs it so you can do bad things with it later.

Comment: e.g. by sending it to a script that logs it so you can do bad things with it later::: what? please explain

Comment: You could steal sessions from other sites if JS was able to access their cookies.

Comment: no its not possible because the cookie of the page do not showed , test the code in the question ;)